# insert input to form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

iam trying to post a file to database,i first created an empty `form` and then tried to add `input` using **javascript**,but i dont know how to link the newly created `input` to form and then submit hence the php shows no result.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>image upload</title>
    <script>
    function sub()
    {
        var form=document.getElementById('nform');      
        var fil1 = document.createElement("input");
        fil1.setAttribute("type","file");
        fil1.setAttribute("name", "image1");
        fil1.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById('one1').value);
        form.submit();                                              
        return
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="nform" action="http://mydomainname.net/somepost.php"method="post">
    </form>

    <input type='file' id="one1"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="sub();" value="Submit">

    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("mydomainname.net","489583788","39853953");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("489583788", $con);

echo $_FILES["image1"]["name"];
echo $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
echo $_FILES["image3"]["name"];      

?>
```

Comment: your input is out side of the form element, it wont be passed to action page.

Comment: fil1.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById('one1').value);  this will do it na?

Comment: Nop, that simply created an dangling object. You need to place it inside the form to be able to submit the value. see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is out side of the form element, it wont be passed to action page. So you need to append it to the form and then submit. Use [**Node.appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```
function sub(){
    var form=document.getElementById('nform');      
    var fil1 = document.createElement("input");
    fil1.setAttribute("type","file");
    fil1.setAttribute("name", "image1");
    fil1.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById('one1').value);
    fil1.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
    form.appendChild(fil1);
    form.submit();                                              
    return
}
```

Comment: but that creates an additional input field inside body when button clicked .

Comment: @EpsilonHades `fil1.setAttribute("style","display:none;");` see the edited answer.

Comment: thanks it worked :-)